# 404 not found trouble making a Wordpress plugin XHR request

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to make a registration form plugin in WordPress. I found a tutorial that I could follow along with and set up a fresh WordPress website using XAMPP. I made the form and fill it in, but for some reason, my file is type html and the method is "GET", which should be "POST" and the type should be XHR ([Network tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xdbd.png)). However, if I don't fill name and surname I don't get 404 response, but still, my type and method don't change. I added 2 files, which I use to make AJAX point to my REST endpoint.

Ajax setup code:

```
<form id="enquiry_form">

<?php wp_nonce_field('wp_rest');?>

<label>Name</label>
<input type="text" name="name">

<label>Surname</label>
<input type="text" name="surname"><br/>

<label>Phone number</label>
<input type="phone" name="phone"><br/>

<label>Institution</label>
<input type="text" name="institution"><br/>

<p>Presentation type</p>
<input type="radio" id="on" name="online" value="0">
<label for="on">Online</label><br>
<input type="radio" id="in" name="inPerson" value="1">
<label for="in">In Person</label>

<button type="submit">Submit</button>

</form>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js">

    jQuery(document).ready(function($){

        $('#enquiry_form').submit(function(event){
            
            event.preventDefault();
            
            var form = $(this);

            console.log(form.serialize());

            $.ajax({

                type: "POST",
                url: "<?php echo get_rest_url(null, 'v1/contact-form/submit');?>",
                data: form.serialize()
            })
        });
        
    });

</script>
```

REST API endpoint code:

```
<?php

add_shortcode('contact', 'show_contact_form');

add_action('rest_api_init', 'create_rest_endpoint');

function show_contact_form()
{
    include PLUGIN_PATH . '/includes/templates/contact-form.php';
}

function create_rest_endpoint()
{
    register_rest_route('v1/contact-form', 'submit', array(

        'methods' => 'POST',
        'callback' => 'handle_enquiry'
    ));
}

function handle_enquiry()
{
    $params = $data->get_params();

    if(!wp_verify_nonce( $params['_wpnonce'], 'wp_rest'))
    {
        return new WP_Rest_Response('Message not sent', 422);
    }

    return new WP_Rest_Response('Message sent', 200);
}
```

I'm new to making requests so I can't figure out what is wrong here.

I changed permalinks, and uninstalled unnecessary plugins, but honestly, I don't know if it's the problem with WordPress or the written code.

Comment: Does the first comment on this page help? I don't use wordpress but it looks like you can get the URL to post to in a different manner

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_rest_url/#user-contributed-notes

Comment: Your form submits the normal way, because you did not actually manage to add any AJAX functionality to it in the first place. Reason - see the duplicate.